Circumventing an email forwarding block on Outlook
There is an M365 School email account that doesn't allow forwarding to other emails from the filters.
Is there a way to circumvent this and still be able to forward emails to another email account which is more frequently checked?
A mail client wouldn't be ideal since this requires it to be constantly running on a desktop computer.
There is an external login functionality that allows any app to connect to M365 but not sure if this can be used.
No problem with running a script 24/7 on some server.

Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see On-Topic. Please talk to your IT department.
